# Error while catching error code for external command from Scala

Tags: scala

I am executing external command from Scala using ! method , but not able to catch exit code , below is the REPL o/p .

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> "ls -lrt CLSTM111.30.SUB#1.D160927.T030108.d.CLSLM001.cls_catg_lkup_EXT.stdout " .!
-rw-r--r-- 1 clsdusr clsdevl 38 Sep 27 03:01 CLSTM111.30.SUB#1.D160927.T030108.d.CLSLM001.cls_catg_lkup_EXT.stdout
res11: Int = 0

scala> println(exitCode)
<console>:35: error: not found: value exitCode
              println(exitCode)
                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The exit code is the return value of `!`. You can do

```
val exitCode = "ls -lrt CLSTM111.30.SUB#1.D160927.T030108.d.CLSLM001.cls_catg_lkup_EXT.stdout ".!

println(exitCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `exitCode` defined in `scala.sys.process`
, but the return value of `!`. From your REPL result it is `res11`. The docs for `ProcessBuilder.!` is as follows:

> Starts the process represented by this builder, blocks until it exits, and returns the exit code.  Standard output and error are sent to the console.